# Why is the first verb in this sentence indefinido, and the second imperfecto

Tags: verbos, pretérito-imperfecto

I am early in learning Spanish, and had a exercise that involved filling in the correct form of the past tense for the following:

> No (tener) ... tiempo de preguntarle al conductor si (poder) ... llevarle

My teacher tells me that the correct answer is:

> No tuve tiempo de preguntarle al conductor si podia llevarle

but the various simple rules I have for indefinido vs imperfecto (e.g. situation vs action, completed vs continuing) don't seem to explain why these two verb uses differ in using indefinido (tuvo) and imperfecto (podia).  Can anyone give a explanation for this case?

Comment: The condition of not having time to ask the driver was presumably something of short duration in the past. On the other hand the (in)ability of the driver to pick the other person up may have lasted for years.

Comment: @medway - thanks - but how would we know that the inability of the driver to pick the other person up was not something entirely restricted to that moment?  And, if I did know that, would I use the indefinido?

Comment: It's very difficult to teach the difference between the preterite and the imperfect to foreigners because, in most cases, there is no "right" answer: it all depends on what the speaker wants to say. "No tuve tiempo..." frames the action as singular and completed, whereas "no tenía tiempo..." frames it as an ongoing event whose beginning and end are not pertinent to the focus of the sentence. As far as the second verb is concerned, "poder llevar" is something that happened over time. It was not a singular action in this sentence; but in other contexts, it could be (Ayer no pudo llevarle nada)

Comment: podia here is could. tuve  is not indefinido. It is the simple past or preterite of tener: pretérito.

Comment: @Lambie - I am used to the terms [pretérito indefinido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preterite#Spanish) and [pretérito imperfecto](https://121spanish.com/preterito-imperfecto).  It looks like people often use pretérito as a short-hand for the pretérito indefinido.

Comment: @MatthewBrett You are right; I am wrong. But what a misnomer. https://www.lawlessspanish.com/grammar/verbs/preterito/

Comment: @MatthewBrett Grammar terminology has changed, What was once known as "pretérito indefinido" is now referred to as "pretérito perfecto simple".

Comment: @Gustavson - thank you for that information.  Can you recommend a definitive reference to find the latest names?

Comment: Here: https://www.rae.es/dpd/ayuda/modelos-de-conjugacion-verbal you have all the model conjugations with the corresponding names for each tense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As regards "podía", the point is that, in indirect speech, the present tense backshifts(*) to the imperfect, not to the preterite. In my dialect, "llevarle" is a case of "leísmo", so I'll use "llevarlo" (or "llevarla") in my explanation below. However, "llevarme" would make more sense to me in that context (the person wanted to know if the driver could take him or her somewhere):

- ¿**Puedo** llevarlo? (Can I take you?) => No tuve tiempo de preguntarle al conductor si **podía** llevarlo (I had no time to ask the driver if I could take him)

More logical:

- ¿**Puede** llevarme? (Can you take me?) => No tuve tiempo de preguntarle al conductor si **podía** llevarme (I had no time to ask the driver if he could take me)

Notice that, just like "could" in English, "podía" in Spanish expresses past ability but not actual performance. The preterite "pude" or "pudo" would be equivalent to "was able to" or "managed to".

As regards the use of "tenía" or "tuve", both would be possible. "Tenía" refers to an ongoing state (I was not in a position to ask him) while "tuve" refers to an actual event (I had no time to ask him).

(*)Note: In indirect or reported speech, "backshifting" consists of retelling a person's statements or thoughts from a past perspective (e.g. Direct speech: **Can** you take me home? => Indirect speech: A ask**ed** B if he **could** take her home)

Comment: I think this answer presupposes more knowledge than the OP has.  Talking about backshifting in speech to the imperfect is pretty complicated.

Comment: @Gustavson - thanks - that's very helpful.  So I think this means I should add another rule to my list - that the imperfecto is used in backshifting the present tense?  And this is somewhat unrelated to the other rules such as 'customary' or 'situation' or 'continuing action'?

Comment: Yes, you should add that rule. I'm happy you understood my reference to backshifting. It was not so cryptic after all :)

Comment: "Backshifting" is a good term to know. I hadn't realized this myself and it's a nice shortcut for explaining this particular situation. One reason why this present→imperfect shift happens is that the present is also an imperfective tense: it shows states and events in progress. So it makes sense that the shift is to an imperfect past tense and not a perfective one.